# Htaccess .php and trailing slash and hash portfolio filter

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, hash

I am using htaccess mod rewrite throughout the site to remove the slash and the .php extension from the pages.

However when I come to the directory and page work/index.php I am having trouble here:
http://thriftandthistle.co.uk/sprout/work/

I want to remove the index.php altogether, but I am having problem due to the hash being used to filter the portfolio.

But with the htaccess I want the php page to read work#print etc to filter the portfolio, but these are just causing the page to redirect with the mod rewrite.

here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp

php_value include_path 'includes'
```

Can anyone help suggest changes I can make to the htaccess to remove the trailing slash and stop the hash redirecting the page instead filter the portfolio?

I have it working on a html page like here: http://thriftandthistle.co.uk/sprout/work.html
but not with the rewrite which seems to cause the problem.

Comment: You should write the hrefs for your selection (print, etc.) like this: work/#print, that should do it.

Comment: I have just updated that, and it still is just refreshing the page and not filtering it. Any idea why?

Comment: it must be work/#print you missed the / before the anchor in your code

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help! Can't believe I missed that! Thanks